# pyodbc cannot connect whereas similar connection works with RODBC

Tags: r, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc, rodbc

I try to connect to my DB with the following request:

```
import pyodbc
connectionString = "driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};database=#DB#;Server=#Server#;port=#port#;UID=#UID#;PWD=#PWD#;"

pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
```

However I get the following error, as if my connection string is not correct:

> Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)')

Which is strange, since I managed to connect to my DB in R with ROBC module.

```
library(RODBC)
ch = odbcDriverConnect(connection = connectionString)
```

Any idea what is wrong with my connection string in pyodbc ?

Comment: What database are you trying to connect to? Do you actually have `#DB#` in your connection string?

Comment: This is a DB developed by Sybase, in SQL, Actually I changed the database name, server address, etc .. for confidentiality.

Comment: EDIT : It is a SYBASE 15.7.0.104 database.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to be much help - I'm not familiar with Sybase or the `Adaptive Server Enterprise` driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem, the request is working with 32-bits python interpreter. 
It appears not to be  64bits compatible.

Similar topic here: [cannot connect to 64bit MsAccess database with 64bit Python 3.6.ODBC Driver Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680554/cannot-connect-to-64bit-msaccess-database-with-64bit-python-3-6-odbc-driver-erro?rq=1)